# Universal properties for groups arising from representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, functors, representable-functor

Consider the forgetful functor $U:\textbf{Grp}\to\textbf{Set}$ and its left adjoint $F$.

The functor $X=\textbf{Set}(A,U(-))$ is represented by $F(A)$, i.e., $X\simeq H^{F(A)}$. By the Yoneda lemma, this gives a unique element $u\in X(F(A))$ (in fact $u=\eta_A$, the unit of the adjunction from the beginning) such that the following universal property holds: for any $p\in X(B)$ there exists a unique $p':F(A)\to B$ such that $p=U(p')\circ \eta_A$.

But the functor $U$ itself is also representable, and I'm a little confused by the universal property that arises in the same manner as above if we write out the details. Here's what I'm getting: $U$ is represented by $F(1)=\mathbb Z$ ($1$ is the singleton set), i.e., there's a natural isomorphism $U\simeq H^{F(1)}=H^\mathbb Z$. This corresponds to some $u\in U(F(1))=U(\mathbb Z)$ that satisfies this universal property:
For any arrow $p:1\to U(B)$, there is a unique arrow $p': \mathbb Z
\to B$ such that $p=U(p')\circ \eta_1$. Is this right? This looks like a castrated version of the universal property above, and I don't know why would anyone use this instead of the comprehensive universal property above. Apparently (if I understand correctly), Leinster deduces from this property that $u$ in this case should be $\pm 1$. Does this make sense (just from what I wrote, without reading Leinster)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$U$ is representable iff $\hom(1,U(-))$ is representable, since these functors are isomorphic. So the second universal property is really a special case of the first. The first is the universal property of any free group, the second is the universal property of the free group in one generator (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition). The universal element here is an element $u \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\hom(\mathbb{Z},G) \to U(G)$, $f \mapsto f(u)$ is bijective for all groups $G$, and this only works for $u=\pm 1$.

Comment: This is not directly related to the answer, but what are universal properties associated to in general? For example, does it make sense to call the first property something like the universal property of the natural isomorphism $H^{F(A)}\simeq X$ and the second one the universal property of the natural isomorphism $H^{F(1)}\simeq U$? If so, then universal properties are associated to natural isomorphisms.